# How do you get the Maya 'list; command to list the render layers in the order they are displayed in the render layer editor?

Tags: python, maya

In Maya, when I list for the render layers in a scene, Maya returns the layers, but not always in the order they are displayed in its' legacy render layer editor. This is true after your change the name of an existing render layer, or add and subtract render layers.  Is there a way to list for the layers and have Maya honor the order used in the render layer editor?

import maya.cmds as cmds
cmds.ls(type = "renderLayer")

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Render layers and display layers have an attribute called "displayOrder" which counts from the bottom -- so #1 is the lowest layer in the UI, #2 is the one above it, and so on.  The default layer always has id 0.

This will get you a dictionary of renderLayers where the keys are the orderings and the values are the layers:

```
render_layers = {
    cmds.getAttr( i + ".displayOrder") : i for i in cmds.ls(type='renderLayer')
}
```

you can turn that into a list in display order:

```
layers_in_order = [render_layers[x] for x in sorted(render_layers.keys())]
```

Answer (score 1):

```
import maya.cmds as mc

renderlayers = sorted(mc.ls(type='renderLayer'), reverse=True, key=lambda r:mc.getAttr(r + ".displayOrder"))

for renderlayer in renderlayers:
    if ':' not in renderlayer:
       print renderlayer
```

the filter for ':' prevents printing renderlayers that are coming from references (like the defaultRenderLayer in every reference file)